# C# A bindinglist saves me the null value in json

Tags: c#, json, datagridview, bindinglist

When i save the json file i hold only a null value, why?
Il'l want to view my datagridview e add in it some row then i'ld want to save the table in a file

```
            private void btn_Salva_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var listadasalvare = dataGridView1.DataSource as List<Rubrica>;

        var listaJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listadasalvare);
        // indico direttamente il percorso senza richiamare la finestra
        // di salvataggio
        var path = @"D:\OneDrive\Corso di c# informatica\Rubricajsonformato.txt";
        File.WriteAllText(path, listaJson);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var formcreate = ClientiDataManager.GetClienti();
        var telefonia = new BindingList<Rubrica>();

        foreach (var campo in formcreate)
        {
            var nuovatelefonia = new Rubrica();
            nuovatelefonia.IdScheda = campo.IdScheda;
            nuovatelefonia.Intestatario = campo.Intestatario;
            nuovatelefonia.NumeroTelefono = campo.NumeroTelefono;
            nuovatelefonia.Scadenza = campo.Scadenza;
            telefonia.Add(nuovatelefonia);



        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = telefonia;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `listadasalvare` is `null`. In the form load event, `var telefonia = new BindingList<Rubrica>();` is a `BindingList<Rubrica>` and it is used as a `DataSource` to the grid. Therefore, when the code cast it as a `List<Rubrica>` in the button click, it will return `null`. Try…

```
var listadasalvare = dataGridView1.DataSource as BindingList<Rubrica>;
```